# ActionSheet keeps appearing for every button

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I have a method which throws up an actionSheet which is populated by an array.

The problem is that as soon as I place that method in the sender for 1 button, it fires off for *every* single button press.

I only want it to display for the one button (btnPortfolio).

Here is the code for my buttons:

```
 - (IBAction)btnPortfolio:(id)sender {
    [self populatePortfolioList];
 }

- (IBAction)btnAdd:(id)sender {

}

- (IBAction)btnRefresh:(id)sender {
}
```

and here is my method:

```
-(void)populatePortfolioList{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose your option"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    for (NSString *title in portfolio_list) {
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
    }
    actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: did you properly connect the buttons in storyboards with the appropriate methods in your code?

Comment: I currently have the bottons connected for the senders/clicks, but what did you mean by connecting to the methods? I have the populatePortfolios method as just a regular method I can call.

Comment: since you are using `IBActions`, I assume that you have somehome created the method by ctrl+dragging from the buttons into your code? is that the case? it might be possible that you accidentally connected more than one of your buttons with the method `btnPortfolio` which causes `populatePortfolioList ` to be called any time the button is pressed

Comment: ah, you were right-the received actions was screwed up in the storyboard.
Thank you nburk

Comment: great! :) I added the comment as an answer, guess it isn't totally complete but if it solved your problem it would be great if you ticked the green checkmark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using `IBActions`, I assume that you have somehow created the methods by ctrl+dragging from the buttons into your code? is that the case? it might be possible that you accidentally connected more than one of your buttons with the method `btnPortfolio` which causes `populatePortfolioList` to be called any time the button is pressed